# Unexplained log simplification, can someone show how?

Tags: logarithms

An online course I am following performs the following $\log$ simplification without explanation:

$$ 9^{\log_3n} = n^2  $$

I am sure this is somewhat simple, but I just cannot see the simplification using the properties of log. I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition

$$y=\log_3n \iff 3^y =n$$

then

$$9^{log_3n} = 9^y=(3\cdot 3)^y=3^y\cdot 3^y=n\cdot n=n^2$$

Answer (score 7):

$\displaystyle 9^{\log_3 n} = 3^{2\log_3 n} = (3^{\log_3 n})^2 = n^2$

Comment: Can you explain the last step? I am not seeing how the term within the parentheses gets simplified to n.

Comment: @Mr.Mips That follows straight from the definition of $\log_3$.